# How can I show correctly Dates yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss with HTML5 and Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, date, datetime

I'm trying to create an input with date and time but I don't get the way of doing it.

I've tried with input **datetime**,

```
<tr>
  <td>Date</td>
    <td><input type="datetime" name="fecha"
    placeholder="dd-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" size="16"
    ng-model="data.action.date" /></td>
  <tt>value = {{data.action.date | date: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}}</tt>
</tr>
```

and I get this

[image]

And I've tried as well input **datetime-local** like the [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5BdateTimeLocal%5D) in angular doc

```
<tr>
  <td>Date</td>
    <td><input type="datetime-local" name="fecha"
    placeholder="dd-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" size="16"
    ng-model="data.action.date" /></td>
  <tt>value = {{data.action.date | date: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}}</tt>
</tr>
```

and I get this

[image]

How could I show the input with a date and time?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the angular-moment directive for doing all date formatting in Angular: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment.

Moment.js is a great JavaScript library for formatting, converting and doing all date/time related tasks - angular-moment just exposes this library easily within Angular.

You can simply use the amDateFormat filter within your template as shown below.

```
<span>{{message.time | amDateFormat:'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}</span>
```

See the above link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using *date* `$filter` component:

```
$scope.tToDisplay = $filter('date')($scope.timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

and bind it to HTML like:

```
<input ng-model="tToDisplay"></input>
```

Make sure to include $filter as a dependency. More [info](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) on the formats.

Comment: Did you try any of the recommended approaches by any chance? Any updates?