# How do i format number to hh:mm in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an input field on my form which is supposed to accept input as number.

However, i would like to format this input number in `hh:mm` format when user enter it? I am not interested in using `input type = time`.

Any idea?

Comment: Perfect scenario for a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Answer (score 1):

You can just write your custom filter:

Read this article: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

or this topic: [How can I show correctly Dates yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss with HTML5 and Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055038/how-can-i-show-correctly-dates-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-with-html5-and-angularjs)

Comment: How can i use custom filter in my html template? Lets say i have "<input type="text" name="classDuration" class="form-control" data-ng-model="ClassDuration" />" and i have customer filter "customFormat" .. How i can use in html?

Comment: Like you use filter in dimple HTML:
<input type="text" name="classDuration" class="form-control" data-ng-model="ClassDuration" | hereYouWriteFilterName />

BTW: On Angular website you can find Everything! Good luck.