# create mask for time input angularjs in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mask, angularjs-filter

I have a code like below in angularjs controller.

```
    $scope.detailConfig = [{
         title: $filter('translate')('bundle.app.HORA_MINUTO_INICIAL_DESCONSIDERAR'),
         property: 'faixaHorariaInicial',
         type: 'text'
     },{
         title: $filter('translate')('bundle.app.HORA_MINUTO_FINAL_DESCONSIDERAR'),
         property: 'faixaHorariaFinal',
         type: 'text'
     }];
```

From this code, I render these two input fields. I need to add time mask for these two inputs so that user can enter time only in this format: hh:mm.

Could you tell me how could I do that, please?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little difficult to know what you're working with when you say you have an input but no tags.  But in JavaScript, if you have a Date object, then you can use the following function to return a string: "hh:mm" as you requested.

```
var myDate = new Date();

function getTime(d) {
    hours = d.getHours();
    minutes = d.getMinutes();
    //seconds = d.getSeconds();
    //return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  return hours + ":" + minutes;
};

var myTime = getTime(myDate);
// returns "10:59"
```

Otherwise, if you do have an html *Input* that you're using, then I would recommend you use one of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055038/how-can-i-show-correctly-dates-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-with-html5-and-angularjs). That will restrict the input to match whatever value you put in the $filter in your controller. In your case, you could write it like this:

```
$scope.tToDisplay = $filter('date')($scope.timestamp, 'HH:mm');
```

and

```
<input ng-model="tToDisplay"></input>
```

Comment: What I need is a mask in my input.

Comment: Can you please share the code you're using for your input?

Comment: there was a specific problem in the system.